# remove class if checkbox disable is true

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I used a custom checkbox, which has hover effect, and although it is disabled, the hover is still there.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MVCuNu3pYOjFeJxk7Vzy?p=preview

So I would like to know is there any way to remove class in angularjs? or with css conditioning?

Comment: Please provide the code for a minimal working example in your question. If that site goes down, or changes something, the question's meaningless.

Comment: @Cerbrus my css is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need angularjs to do that, you can use :enabled pseudo-class. Just change your CSS to:

```
.checkbox label:hover:enabled::after{
opacity: 1;
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/z1mu2y6V5fN6tJLn9ebr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Jqlite in angularjs provides **removeClass()** method for removing the class from the element.
 You can call that using angular.element(element).removeClass().